# How to scrape Star Rating from Etsy HTML with Python?

Tags: python, html, pandas, regex, web-scraping

I can not find a way to extract the star rating from each product from the Etsy source code.

This is the code I've used to extract the description, price, number of reviews from a set of text files containing several Etsy webpage source code for several products. The only bit not working is the star rating which I cannot get to extract to my dataframe. Any ideas on how I could point it to be scraped and list them on my dataframe?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import re

directory_path = r"C:\Users\..."

descriptions = []
prices = []
review_numbers = []
file_names = []
stars = []

for file_name in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if file_name.endswith(".txt"):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, file_name)
        
        with open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            description = ""
            price = ""
            review_number = ""
            star_rating = ""
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith('----------------------------------------'):
                    if description != "":
                        descriptions.append(description.strip())
                        prices.append(price)
                        review_numbers.append(review_number)
                        file_names.append(file_name)
                        stars.append(star_rating)

                    description = ""
                    price = ""
                    review_number = ""
                    star_rating = ""
                elif re.match(r'\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?', line):
                    price = line.strip()
                elif re.search(r'\(\d[\d,]*\)', line):
                    review_number = re.search(r'\(\d[\d,]*\)', line).group()
                else:
                    description += line.strip() + " "

                star_match = re.search(r'class="wt-align-items-center wt-max-height-full wt-display-flex-xs flex-direction-row-xs wt-text-title-small wt-no-wrap">([\d.]+)', line)
                if star_match:
                    star_rating = star_match.group(1)

                if 'v2-listing-card_title' in line:
                    description = line.split('title="', 1)[1].split('"', 1)[0]

            if description != "":
                descriptions.append(description.strip())
                prices.append(price)
                review_numbers.append(review_number)
                file_names.append(file_name)
                stars.append(star_rating)

data = {'Description': descriptions, 'Price': prices, 'Review_Number': review_numbers, 'File_Name': file_names, 'Stars': stars}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Here is a typical example of the kind of webpage I'm trying to scrape:
https://www.etsy.com/search?q=halloween+shirt&explicit=1&ship_to=FR&price_bucket=1&max=20&ref=search_bar

The HTML snippet containing the stars looks like this:

```
<b><div class="v2-listing-card_info

<h3 class="wt-text-caption v2-listing-card_title wt-text-truncate

title="Luna moth cape dance win gs costume adult Spanish luna moth cape chiffon be lly halloween burning man" id="ad-listing-title-2 80310434"></h3>

<div class="streamline-spacing-shop-rating">

<div class="shop-name-with-rating wt-flex-wrap w t-display-flex-xs flex-direction-row-xs wt-align -items-center"> flex

<span class="

wt-display-inline-flex-xs wt-flex-wrap wt-align-items-center larger_review_stars

">Flex $0

<div role="img" aria-label="4.9 star rating with 15.4k reviews" class="wt-align-items-ce nter wt-max-height-full wt-display-flex-xs f lex-direction-row-xs wt-text-title-small wt- no-wrap"> flex

"4.9"</b>
```

The output looks as follows, with the column for stars completely empty:

| Description | Price | Review_Number | File_Name | Stars |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Applied thermostickers witch shoes in liberty ... | $6.89 | (801) | halloween_cape_0-20_clean.txt |  |
| Cute Cat with a witch hat Sticker / Cute Kitty... | $3.68 | (30) | halloween_cape_0-20_clean.txt |  |
| Navy Velvet Wizard Costume Skirt Tutu Cape Wan... | $18.57 | (3,990) | halloween_cape_0-20_clean.txt |  |
| Dog Cape - "QUEEN ELIZABETH" ... | $17.26 | (25) | halloween_cape_0-20_clean.txt |  |
| Vampire cat halloween artwork, Halloween cat p... | $25.69 | (427) | halloween_cape_0-20_clean.txt |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Jack Skellington XXL Bow Tie Necklace - Eyes T... | $57.52 | (104) | halloween_tie_50-100_clean.txt |  |
| Vintage Halloween Season of the Witch Novel by... | $79.57 | (1,650) | halloween_tie_50-100_clean.txt |  |
| Halloween Tie Dye Sweatshirt // Orange, Purple... | $50.00 | (755) | halloween_tie_50-100_clean.txt |  |
| Loading... |  |  | halloween_tie_50-100_clean.txt |  |

Comment: Are you looking for a Regex or not ? Do you want to do this with a regex ? If not, please remove the regex tag. Scraping is the use of regex to blow past possible malformed html.

Answer (score 0):

To parse the HTML you should use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) over regex - Just a simple example based on HTML that should be in one of your files:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html = '''<div class="v2-listing-card__info "> <h3 class="wt-text-caption v2-listing-card__title wt-text-truncate " title="Halloween-T-Shirt mit buntem Totenkopf-T-Shirt, Tag der Toten-Shirt, Dia de Los Muertos-Totenkopf-Blumen-T-Shirt" id="ad-listing-title-1543583272"> Halloween-T-Shirt mit buntem Totenkopf-T-Shirt, Tag der Toten-Shirt, Dia de Los Muertos-Totenkopf-Blumen-T-Shirt </h3> <div class="streamline-spacing-shop-rating"> <div class="shop-name-with-rating wt-flex-wrap wt-display-flex-xs flex-direction-row-xs wt-align-items-center"> <span class=" wt-display-inline-flex-xs wt-flex-wrap wt-align-items-center larger_review_stars "> <div role="img" aria-label="5.0-Sterne-Bewertung bei 5&nbsp;Bewertungen" class="wt-align-items-center wt-max-height-full wt-display-flex-xs flex-direction-row-xs wt-text-title-small wt-no-wrap"> 5.0<span class="wt-icon wt-icon--smaller-xs"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 1 24 24" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <path d="M20.828 9.154l-6.008-.528-2.36-5.545h-.92L9.18 8.626l-6.007.528-.284.876 4.548 3.954-1.353 5.871.744.541 5.172-3.1 5.172 3.1.744-.54-1.352-5.871 4.548-3.955-.284-.876z"></path></svg></span><p class="wt-text-body-smaller">(5)</p> </div></span> <span class="wt-text-title-small wt-text-gray search-half-unit-ml search-half-unit-mr">·</span> <p class="wt-text-caption wt-text-truncate keg7kF44I9 wt-text-body-smaller streamline-seller-shop-name__line-height"> <span class="wt-icon zof5z176j wt-icon--smallest-xs wt-bg-white wt-nudge-b-1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <path d="M19 13a1 1 0 00-1 1v1H6v-1a1 1 0 10-2 0v7a1 1 0 001 1h14a1 1 0 001-1v-7a1 1 0 00-1-1zm-1 7H6v-3h12v3zm-.15-17.53A1 1 0 0017 2H7a1 1 0 00-.85.47L2 9a3.77 3.77 0 001.12 2.09 3.47 3.47 0 002.35.91 3.51 3.51 0 003.26-2.23 3.51 3.51 0 006.53 0A3.51 3.51 0 0018.53 12c.866 0 1.7-.325 2.34-.91A3.77 3.77 0 0022 9l-4.15-6.53zM4.43 9l3.12-5h8.89l3.13 5H4.43z"></path></svg></span> <span class="zof5z176j" aria-hidden="true">Anzeige des Etsy-Shops</span> <span class="zof5z176j wt-screen-reader-only">Anzeige des Etsy-Shops</span> <span class="pxyglo796" aria-hidden="true">TeerificStyle</span> <span class="pxyglo796 wt-screen-reader-only">Aus dem Shop TeerificStyle</span> </p> </div> </div> <div class="n-listing-card__price wt-display-flex-xs wt-align-items-center wt-width-full wt-flex-wrap wt-width-full wt-text-title-01 lc-price "> <p class="wt-text-title-01 lc-price"> ab <span class="currency-value">14,42</span> <span class="currency-symbol">€</span> </p></div> <div class="streamline-spacing-pricing-info streamline-spacing-reduce-margin"> </div> </div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []
for card in soup.select('.v2-listing-card__info'):
    data.append({
        'description':card.h3.get_text(strip=True),
        'price': card.select_one('.currency-value').get_text(strip=True),
        'stars':card.select_one('h3 + div [role="img"]').contents[0],
        'reviews':card.select_one('h3 + div p').get_text(strip=True)
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In addition, try to avoid the bunch of lists and store your data in a more structured way also to simply create your dataframe from there.